# Combined conversion

Tags: c++

I just started to study informatics. Now i got my first task and i,am full of questions. Does someone have some advice for me?
The task is to create an math formula which allows to decide between 3 different formula without any kind of "switch, if-else or other operators" 
Sooo goal is it to just 
cin a number;
decide with cin 1, 2 or 3 between Celsius to Fahrenheit, meters in foot or € in $ and gettin a result. Im pretty new and just asking me for like 2 hours what such a formula would look like D:
any idea?

My Actual Code looks like this. (we arent allowed to use any kind of code we hadnt in our lectures yet. Allowed are just: value assignment, variables, simply data types , basic calculus, cins and couts..

Im just curious on that formula which does not get into my head and how to code it...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double eingabe;
    int auswahl = 0;
    double ergebnis;


    //zahleneingabe
    cout << "Ihre Eingabe: ? " << endl;
    cin >> eingabe;
    cout << "Ihre Eingabe: " << eingabe << endl;

    system("PAUSE");


    //abfragenausgabe der umrechnungsart
    cout << "Ihre Auswahl der Umwandlung: " << endl;
    cout << "1 - Celsius in Fahrenheit" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Meter in Fuss" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Euro in US Dollar " << endl;

    cin >> auswahl;

    cout << "Ihr Ergebnis ist: " << ergebnis << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please show your [mcve] ***as text***. An image is impossible to copy and try for ourselves, and impossible for screen-readers to parse, or search engines to index

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, but as text.

Comment: Are arrays allowed?  Also take a look at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Doesn't matter for such small projects, but could be useful for the future.

Comment: Sadly arrays are not allowed. Trying to get trough it with modulo only or an F function. Sadly im to bad at it =3=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use modulo to your advantage.

Assume the formulae:

```
const float fahrenheitConst = 9.f/5.f;
const float feetConst = 3.2f;
const float exchangeRate = 1.11f;


// eingabe = x, auswahl = y
double a = x * fahrenheitConst + 32;
double b = x * feetConst;
double c = x * exchangeRate;

double result = ( y % 3 ) * ( y % 2 ) * a + ( ( y + 2 ) % 3 ) * ( y + 1 ) % 2 * b + ( y + 1 ) % 3 * ( ( y - 1 ) / 2 ) * c
```

---

### Explanation

Basically we want a formula, that is a sum of three terms, where each term is the result of a subformula and two coefficients. For every input, the coefficients for one of the three terms must result in `1` each, while the coefficients for the other two terms must include at least one `0` coefficient per term. To put differently, we want only one of the three subformulae *a*, *b* or *c* to be part of `result` and its magnitude needs to be exactly `1`.

1. `y % 3` results in `0` for `3` and in `1` for `1`
2. `y % 2` results in `0` for `2` and in `1` for `1`
3. `( y + 2 ) % 3` results in `0` for `1` and in `1` for `2`
4. `( y + 1 ) % 2` results in `0` for `3` and in `1` for `2`
5. `( y + 1 ) % 3` results in `0` for `2` and in `1` for `3`
6. `( ( y - 1 ) / 2 )` results in `0` for `1` and in `1` for `3` (cannot use `% 1`)

### Demonstration

1. Let input be `1`:

```
result = ( 1 % 3 ) * ( 1 % 2 ) * a + ( ( 1 + 2 ) % 3 ) * ( 1 + 1 ) % 2 * b + ( 1 + 1 ) % 3 * ( ( 1 - 1 ) / 2 ) * c
= 1 * 1 * a + 0 * 0 * b + 1 * ( 0 / 2 ) * c
= 1 * a + 0 * b + 0 * c
= a
```

2. Let input be `2`:

```
result = ( 2 % 3 ) * ( 2 % 2 ) * a + ( ( 2 + 2 ) % 3 ) * ( 2 + 1 ) % 2 * b + ( 2 + 1 ) % 3 * ( ( 2 - 1 ) / 2 ) * c
= 1 * 0 * a + 1 * 1 * b + 0 * [1/2 --> 0 in INT] * c
= 0 * a + 1 * b + 0 * c
= b
```

1. Let input be `3`:

```
result = ( 3 % 3 ) * ( 3 % 2 ) * a + ( ( 3 + 2 ) % 3 ) * ( 3 + 1 ) % 2 * b + ( 3 + 1 ) % 3 * ( ( 3 - 1 ) / 2 ) * c
= 0 * 1 * a + 2 * 0 * b + 1 * 1 * c
= 0 * a + 0 * b + 1 * c 
= c
```

### Notes

There is an ambiguity in the division, that depends on the types used, this is where I wrote `[1/2 --> 0 in INT]`. That is because for **float** or **double** this results in `1/2`, but for **int** this results in `0`. Please note how this makes absolutely no difference here. The result could be `5000`, but as long as the previous factor results in `0`, the whole term resolves to `0`.

Additionally you could use integer division to your advantage, *i.e.* dividing a smaller numer by a larger number will result in `0` for **int** . I chose not to go that way, because OP mentioned a mathematical solution, while taking advantage of integer division is rather a programmatical approach.

### Conclusion

Use:

```
result = c1 * c2 * formula1 + c3 * c4 * formula2 + c5 * c6 * formula3
```

So that only the coefficients `c_i` for one of the three formulae resolve to exactly `1` each, while for the other coefficients at least one per formula must resolve in `0`.

Answer (score 2):

If Yasir's solution still uses features that aren't to your teacher's liking (`operator ==` might be forbidden as well), the remaining solution is polynomial regression...

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //zahleneingabe
    std::cout << "Ihre Eingabe: ?\n";

    double eingabe;
    std::cin >> eingabe;
    std::cout << "Ihre Eingabe: " << eingabe << '\n';

    //abfragenausgabe der umrechnungsart
    std::cout << "Ihre Auswahl der Umwandlung:\n";
    std::cout << "1 - Celsius in Fahrenheit\n";
    std::cout << "2 - Meter in Fuss\n";
    std::cout << "3 - Euro in US Dollar\n";

    int auswahl;
    std::cin >> auswahl;

    // Found using http://www.xuru.org/rt/PR.asp (ain't nobody got time for that)
    double const coefficient = (-1.82584 * auswahl + 6.95836) * auswahl - 3.33252;
    double const offset = (16.0 * auswahl - 80.0) * auswahl + 96.0;

    double const ergebnis = eingabe * coefficient + offset;

    std::cout << "Ihr Ergebnis ist: " << ergebnis << '\n';
}
```

Note that I have also cleaned up the code by [removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) `using namespace std;`, rescoping variables to their actual use, and added `const` where relevant. I leave it to you to translate the new variables to german ;)

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2Gw9N6eYGoLJUdLH)

Comment: That's a pretty slick solution, could you please share some explanation on how this is working? I am slightly familiar with regression between 2 variables but what are the variables in this case?

Comment: @YasirKhan the three points of interest are (1, 1.8), (2, 3.28084), (3, 1.11), which map `auswahl` to `coefficient`. Same thing for `offset` with values 32, 0, 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it makes sense now. A very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem. I can't think of anything else that solves it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double eingabe;
    int auswahl = 0;
    double ergebnis;

    //zahleneingabe
    cout << "Ihre Eingabe: ? " << endl;
    cin >> eingabe;
    cout << "Ihre Eingabe: " << eingabe << endl;


    //abfragenausgabe der umrechnungsart
    cout << "Ihre Auswahl der Umwandlung: " << endl;
    cout << "1 - Celsius in Fahrenheit" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Meter in Fuss" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Euro in US Dollar " << endl;

    cin >> auswahl;

    double feet_conv = 3.28084;
    double dollar_conv = 1.11;

    ergebnis = (auswahl == 1) * ((eingabe * 9.0 / 5) + 32) + 
               (auswahl == 2) *  eingabe * feet_conv +
               (auswahl == 3) * eingabe * dollar_conv;

     cout << "Ihr Ergebnis ist: " << ergebnis << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: OP said no *if-else*, *switch* or other operators. You used the *ternary* operator to model *switch* - from what I read in the opening question this is not allowed.

Comment: Your function pointer answer was good (+1). It didn't need the ternary operator update - just confuses the answer.

Comment: It also uses an array which again, according to OP, is not allowed

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have edited my solution to not use function pointers, arrays, and conditional operator. I can't think of any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can do without `if`/`switch` or ternary operator, or comparison, just boolean operations, implicit bool-to-integer conversion, and multiplication:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double c_zu_f(double in)     { return in * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0; }
double m_zu_ft(double in)    { return 3.0 * in; }  // approx.
double eur_zu_usd(double in) { return 1.2 * in; }  // approx.

int main()
{
    double eingabe;
    int auswahl = 0;
    double ergebnis;

    //zahleneingabe
    cout << "Ihre Eingabe: ? " << endl;
    cin >> eingabe;
    cout << "Ihre Eingabe: " << eingabe << endl;

    system("PAUSE");


    //abfragenausgabe der umrechnungsart
    cout << "Ihre Auswahl der Umwandlung: " << endl;
    cout << "1 - Celsius in Fahrenheit" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Meter in Fuss" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Euro in US Dollar " << endl;

    cin >> auswahl;



    bool auswahl_gueltig  = auswahl && (auswahl & 0x03);  // oder nur (auswahl & 0x03), da 0 --> false
    bool auswahl_ist_eins = auswahl_gueltig &&  ( (auswahl & 1) && !(auswahl & 2));
    bool auswahl_ist_zwei = auswahl_gueltig &&  (!(auswahl & 1) &&  (auswahl & 2));
    bool auswahl_ist_drei = auswahl_gueltig && !( auswahl_ist_eins || auswahl_ist_zwei );

    ergebnis = auswahl_ist_eins * c_zu_f(eingabe) + auswahl_ist_zwei * m_zu_ft(eingabe) + auswahl_ist_drei * eur_zu_usd(eingabe);

    cout << "Ihr Ergebnis ist: " << ergebnis << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

If given invalid (not 1, 2, or 3) `auswahl`, the result shown will be zero, but that's as good as you can get without `if` or ternary operator (though you could `assert(auswahl_gueltig)` of course, which isn't exactly the same but at least won't fail *silently*).

Can make the implicit `bool` to `int` conversion explicit with a cast, too, if you like -- but that's unnecessary and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Give an integer named `choice` representing the user's choice, the following expression evaluates to 0 when the the user chooses 1 or 2 and it evaluates to 1 when the user chooses 3:

```
(choice - 1) * (choice - 2) * 0.5
```

Therefore, this expression is a pretty good replacement for `choice == 3`, which you are not allowed to use in this homework problem because it contains `==`.

With the hint above, you can probably guess what to do.  But here is a complete solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double input;
  std::cout << "Enter your input: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> input;

  int choice;
  std::cout << "Choose your conversion: " << std::endl;
  std::cout << "1: Celsius to Fahrenheit" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "2: Meters to feet" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "3: Euros to US Dollars" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> choice;

  double result =
    (choice - 2) * (choice - 3) * 0.5 * (1.8 * input + 32) +  // C to F
    (choice - 1) * (choice - 3) * -1  * (3.28084 * input) +   // m to ft
    (choice - 1) * (choice - 2) * 0.5 * (0.97 * input)        // Euro to USD
  ;
  std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
}
```